# Join postgres table on two columns?

Tags: postgresql

I can't find a straightforward answer. My query is spitting out the wrong result, and I think it's because it's not seeing the "AND" as an actual join.

Can you do something like this and if not, what is the correct approach:

```
SELECT * from X
LEFT JOIN Y
ON
  y.date = x.date AND y.code = x.code
```

?

Comment: What are the expected are actual results?

Comment: The syntax is correct - otherwise you'd get an error message. Your description "spitting out wrong results" doesn't tell us anything about your problem though. You have to show us some sample data and the expected output. Ideally create a little example on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is possible:

> The ON clause is the most general kind of join condition: it takes a Boolean value expression of the same kind as is used in a WHERE clause. A pair of rows from T1 and T2 match if the ON expression evaluates to true for them.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM

Your SQL looks OK.

Answer (score 59):

It's fine. In fact, you can put *any* condition in the ON clause, even one
not related to the key columns or even the the tables at all, eg:

```
SELECT * from X
LEFT JOIN Y
    ON y.date = x.date
    AND y.code = x.code
    AND EXTRACT (dow from current_date) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another, arguably more readable way of writing the join is to use tuples of columns:

```
SELECT * from X
LEFT JOIN Y
ON
  (y.date, y.code) = (x.date, x.code)
;
```

, which clearly indicates that the join is based on the equality on several columns.

Answer (score -5):

This solution has good performance:

```
select * from(
   select md5(concat(date, code)) md5_x from x ) as x1
left join (select md5(concat(date, code)) md5_y from y) as y1
on x1.md5_x = y1.md5_y
```

Comment: Downvoting:

1) This only performs well for large data sets if you actually have an index on `md5(concat(date, code))`.
2) Hashes (like MD5) are not guaranteed to be unique, and actually by their very nature are not. This means you might inadvertently join in unintended records this way just because their MD5 hashes happen to be the same.
3) You gave absolutely no explanation for why this "has good performance" and why it's even an answer to the original question.